# Add character after each fourth symbol of the string

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have string like that `"blabllabnsdfsdfsd"`
I want to make it `"blab-llab-nsdf-sdfs"`

Is it doable with `Regex.Replace` somehow?
What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please notice that you have 2 different types of answers ... depending on the person who answered interpretation of "keep or lose characters at the end" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string bla = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";

bla = Regex.Replace(bla, ".{4}", "$0-");
bla = bla.Remove(bla.Length - 1);
```

Comment: This is pretty much how I would have done it, except in ruby: ```puts "blabllabnsdfsdfsd".scan(/(.{4})/).join("-")```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to make another string copy this string into that one character by character and add a `-` after each 4 characters.

```
string a = "abcdefghijklmn";
List<char> b= new List<char>();
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    b.Add('-');
    b.Add(a[i]);
}

String result = new String(b.ToArray()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say a for loop.

```
for( i = 0 ; i < string.length ; i+4){
   string.addAtPosition(i , "-");
}
```

the function name depends on the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
{
    if(i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
        newStr += "-" + str[i];
    else
        newStr += str[i];
 }
```

Here you go.
You take the modulo from the division to conclude it is the 4th char.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be :

```
string s = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int position = 0;
// add a `-` every 4 chars
while (position < s.Length -4) // the (-4) is to avoid the last `-`
{
    sb.Append(s.Substring(position, 4));
    sb.Append("-");
    position += 4;
}
sb.Append(s.Substring(position)); // Adds the last part of the string
Console.Out.WriteLine("out" + sb.ToString());
```

Output: `blab-llab-nsdf-sdfs-d`

you could play around with it ... You could run the loop with a `while (position <s.Length)` (without the -4, and then just trim the string to remove the last `-`, and so on.

Hehe, just noticed i have an extra `d` in my input, so hence, the extra `-d` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Tried and tested**

```
List<String> str = new List<String>();

String myString = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i = i + 4)
{
    index = i;
    if (myString.Length >= index + 4)
        str.Add(myString.Substring(index, 4));
}

myString = String.Join("-", str.ToArray());
```

**Here is proof**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question seems simple however looking at the range of answers there is a lot of different ways to implement this. Here's my take on it assuming that you want to keep the last characters after the final dash `-`

```
var value = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";

const int lengthOfSeperator = 4;

for (var i = 0; i <= Math.Floor(value.Length / (decimal)lengthOfSeperator); i++)
{
    if (lengthOfSeperator + (lengthOfSeperator * i) + i > value.Length) continue;
    value = value.Insert(lengthOfSeperator + (lengthOfSeperator * i) + i, "-");
}
```

Returns `blab-llab-nsdf-sdfs-d`

Answer (score 0):

A quick one-liner:

```
        string blab = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";
        string blab2 = String.Join("-", Regex.Matches(blab, ".{1,4}").OfType<Match>().Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(blab);
        Console.WriteLine(blab2);
```

As a String Extension:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string blab = "blabllabnsdfsdfsd";
        string blab2 = blab.Chunk("-", 4);
        Console.WriteLine(blab);
        Console.WriteLine(blab2);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Chunk(this String str, string separator, int groupsOf)
    {
        string[] chunks = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
            .Matches(str, ".{1," + groupsOf.ToString() + "}")
            .OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
            .Select(s => s.ToString())
            .ToArray();
        return String.Join(separator, chunks);
    }
}
```